# Send an email through Salesforce server from External Application

Tags: rest-api, api, email-template, salesforce2salesforce

I have an angular application, and wants to send an email to Salesforce contacts from external application through salesforce server.

I did not find any api or javascript file which allows me to write the code to send an email through salesforce server from external application.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to save it as an Activity? Why does it need to go through Salesforce?

Comment: if i send it through salesforce server, it makes sure, it sends to the recipients. We can also send from our mail domain. but, usually salesforce is well-known , and people will definitely open the email.